# Webscraping is buggy through AWS Lambda, but works fine in VS Code and on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, aws-lambda, python-requests

My dependencies are fine, Lambda doesn't create any errors, code runs smoothly. I also checked memory (512MB) and timeout (5 mins). Just instead of a list of HTML divs I'm getting a list of empty lists. Interestingly there are quite a few lists nested, so it might even be the number of divs I'm trying to scrape, they're just completely empty.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    url3='https://www.szybko.pl/l/na-sprzedaz/lokal-mieszkalny/Wroc%C5%82aw?assetType=lokal-mieszkalny&localization_search_text=Wroc%C5%82aw&market=aftermarket&price_min_sell=200000&price_max_sell=400000&meters_min=30&rooms_min=2'

    def get_last_page3(url):
        result = requests.get(url)
        source = result.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
        last_page = soup.find_all("li",{'class': 'blank'})[1].text
        
        return int(last_page)


    def get_list_of_soups3(url):
        
        list_of_soups=[]
        
        for page in range(1,get_last_page3(url)+1):
            try:
                result = requests.get(url+'&strona='+str(page))
                source = result.content
                soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
                ads = soup.find_all("div",{'class': "gt-listing-item-asset listing-item"}) 
                list_of_soups.append(ads)
                
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                break
                
        return list_of_soups


    all_ads3 = []

    try:
        for soup in get_list_of_soups3(url3):
            for s in soup:
                name = s.find("a")['aria-label'].replace('Szczegóły ogłoszenia - ','')
                district  = s.find("a",{'class': 'mapClassClick list-elem-address popup-gmaps'}).text.replace('\n','').replace('  ','').replace(', dolnośląskie','')
                price = s.find("span",{'class': 'listing-price'}).text.strip().replace(' zł','').replace(' ','')[:6]
                rooms = s.find("li",{'class': 'asset-feature rooms'}).text.replace(' ','')
                sq = s.find("li",{'class': 'asset-feature area'}).text.replace('m²','').replace(',','.')
                price_sq = s.find("span",{'class': 'listing-price'}).find('i').text.replace('zł/m²','').replace(' ','').strip()
                link = s.find('a')['href'].strip()

                ad=[name,district,int(price),int(rooms),round(float(sq)),int(price_sq),link]
                all_ads3.append(ad)
                            
    except Exception as e:
        print('error: website changed or unresponsive',e)

    return get_list_of_soups3(url3)
```

Also, a similar code scraping a similar website works perfectly fine from both IDE and Lambda. Both Lambdas are configured in the same way.

I'm using Python with requests and beautiful soup libraries.

Comment: Any error messages? Have you inspected CloudWatch Logs?

Comment: Some websites block requests coming from Amazon IP ranges to prevent unwanted web scraping. Do _any_ of the pages return data?

Comment: @Marcin, no error messages.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, yes 3 other pages return data

Comment: Have you tried running the code on an EC2 instance if this is lambda specific issue or rather AWS, like John suggested?

Comment: it's working in EC2, seems it's Lambda specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by changing the HTML class of divs scraped in the second function. I achived this with print statement debugging.

Not sure what is the reason, my guess would be that maybe Lambda couldn't handle a photothumbnail that was included in the original div? Maybe something to do with the way ads are generated on this particular website?

Code also includes my print statements in comments and has try/except removed. The crucial change in line 29: `ads = soup.find_all("div",{'class': "listing-content"})`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # # Scraping url3: szybko.pl

    url3='https://www.szybko.pl/l/na-sprzedaz/lokal-mieszkalny/Wroc%C5%82aw?assetType=lokal-mieszkalny&localization_search_text=Wroc%C5%82aw&market=aftermarket&price_min_sell=200000&price_max_sell=400000&meters_min=30&rooms_min=2'

    def get_last_page3(url):
        result = requests.get(url)
        source = result.content
        #print('SOURCE:',source)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
        last_page = soup.find_all("li",{'class': 'blank'})[1].text
        print('PAGE:',last_page)
        return int(last_page)


    def get_list_of_soups3(url):
        list_of_soups=[]
        for page in range(1,get_last_page3(url)+1):
            try:
                result = requests.get(url+'&strona='+str(page))
                #print('RESULT:',result)
                source = result.content
                soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
                #print('SOUP:',soup) #it's fine
                ads = soup.find_all("div",{'class': "listing-content"})
                #print('ADS:',ads)
                list_of_soups.append(ads)
                
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                break
            
        return list_of_soups


    all_ads3 = []
    for soup in get_list_of_soups3(url3):
        for s in soup:
            name = s.find("a",{'class': 'listing-title-heading hide-overflow-text'}).find("div",{'class': "tooltip"}).text#.replace('Szczegóły ogłoszenia - ','')
            district  = s.find("a",{'class': 'mapClassClick list-elem-address popup-gmaps'}).text.replace('\n','').replace('  ','').replace(', dolnośląskie','').strip()
            price = s.find("div",{'class': 'listing-title'}).find_all("span")[2]['content']#.text.strip().replace(' zł','').replace(' ','')[:6]
            rooms = s.find("li",{'class': 'asset-feature rooms'}).text.replace(' ','')
            sq = s.find("li",{'class': 'asset-feature area'}).text.replace('m²','').replace(',','.')
            price_sq = int(price)/round(float(sq))
            link = s.find('a')['href'].strip()
    
            ad=[name,district,int(price),int(rooms),round(float(sq)),int(price_sq),link]
            all_ads3.append(ad)
    
    return len(all_ads3)
```